# Is there a function with random humps?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Is there an $(1)$ infinitely differentiable function that $(2)$ crosses the $x$-axis at and only at every integer where $(3)$ the pattern of the humps' sign is computable but not only by looking at whether every other hump is positive or negative.

For instance, $\sin (\pi x)$ has humps that go ...^v^v^v^v^v... so it doesn't meet $(3)$.

$\sin(\sin(\pi x/2))-\sin(1)\sin(\pi x/2)$ has humps that go ...^^vv^^vv^^vv... so again $(3)$ is the limiting factor.

I was thinking there might be a way to have a function that you can plug in $1$'s and $-1$'s in certain places to make the humps be positive and negative on every interval between integers.

Comment: What does your third criterion mean?

Comment: the sign of the function is random basically, but due to the nature of the other criteria, it will be humps, like a sine wave

Comment: The fact that such a function exists should be obvious.  Consider two basic buildingblocks and their negatives: high-to-high, high-to-low where these building blocks are some convenient scaling and shifting of a sine function which always touches the $x$-axis on integer values.  Paste these together according to some "random"-esque pattern, for example according to whether or not the $n$'th digit of $\pi$ is even or odd (*if even, change from low to high or vice versa and if odd stay low-to-low or high-to-high*).

Comment: your second example touches the $x$ axis at each half-integer, doesn't this disqualify it from consition (2) as well? Just to clarify the rusles, since this would be easily fixed with $x\rightarrow x/2$

Comment: Do you mind what happens at negative $x$'s?

Comment: Negatives matter. And it doesn't really matter what the period is I guess since it can be transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your function:

$$
(-1)^{\lfloor \pi \cdot 10^{\lfloor x\rfloor} + \sqrt 2 \cdot 10^{\lfloor -x\rfloor}\rfloor \text{ mod } 10} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{\sin^2(\pi x)}}
$$

where $\pi$ and $\sqrt 2$ in the first exponent have been chosen randomly amongst allegedly [normal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) and can be replaced at will. The first one takes care of the random distribution of humps for positive $x$'s and the other one for negatives.

Obviously the function has to be completed for continuity at each integer $x$.